# SQL to remove duplicates on one column and then aggregating duplicates on another column without using "partition" keyword

Tags: sql, db2, filtering

With the following query:

```
SELECT STAT, SHNO, ORDERNO FROM  BLUEWATER ORDER BY SHNO;
```

I can get the following:

```
STAT      SHNO     ORDERNO                                                                                                                                     
40      ASN123   40303020                                                                                                                                    
40      ASN123   40303020                                                                                                                                    
30      ASN124   40303021                                                                                                                                    
30      ASN124   40303021                                                                                                                                    
30      ASN125   40303021
```

I am looking for a query that will eliminate duplicate SHNO rows and then create a fourth column that is a sum of the number of ORDERNO repeats (this total is calculated after having  eliminated SHNO duplicates).

The target database is DB2. I currently don't know what version but will seek to ascertain this although I am assuming not a recent version.

My goal is a query that produces the following:

```
STAT      SHNO     ORDERNO  ORDERNOTOTAL                                                                                                                    
40      ASN123   40303020    1                                                                                                                               
30      ASN124   40303021    2                                                                                                                               
30      ASN125   40303021    2
```

The solution need to avoid use of the PARTITION keyword as this version of DB2 doesn't accept it.

Comment: Which following query?  can you post the code that generates the first example?

Comment: by sum do you mean count? If so asn123 and asn125 in  your required example look like they are the wrong way round?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with DB2, but the following would work in most SQL versions:

```
SELECT STAT, SHNO, ORDERNO, count(1) OrderNoTotal
FROM  BLUEWATER 
GROUP BY STAT, SHNO, ORDERNO
ORDER BY SHNO;
```

---

@JohnLBevan

Your solution provides the following:

```
STAT      SHNO     ORDERNO    ORDERNOTOTAL  
40     ASN123      40303020    2
30     ASN124      40303021    2
30     ASN125      40303021    1
```

Whereas I'm seeking this:

```
STAT      SHNO     ORDERNO    ORDERNOTOTAL  
40     ASN123      40303020    1
30     ASN124      40303021    2
30     ASN125      40303021    2
```

There are two records that have 40303021 so next to each one is the value 2 in ORDERNOTOTAL

---

**Update based on above comment**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ab95/3

```
select STAT
, SHNO
, ORDERNO
, count(shno) over (partition by OrderNo) OrderNoTotal
from BLUEWATER
group by STAT
, SHNO
, ORDERNO
```

Comment: But what if two rows have equal SHNO value, but different STAT and ORDERING values, then those will be two different groups, and the purpose of this query to get rid of duplicate SHNO, shouldn't you remove SHNO from the group?

Comment: They shouldnt have different STAT values as I will be updating all STATS values for a SHNO to the same value.

Comment: @kolonel: If you had different values then yes, you'd get additional rows.  However, if you have different values, how would you display both values for the same column in the same row?  You could get around that by only displaying the 1 of the 2 values (e.g. using `min(STAT) over (partition by SHNO order by STAT)` or similar), but my guess (based on the sample data) is that's not what was wanted.

Comment: @JohnLBevan unfortunately the DB2 database doesn't like the use of partition. Is there a way around it ? I read something on a forum that might be related: http://forums.iprodeveloper.com/forums/aft/148438

Answer (score 0):

DB2 should be fine with partition, but you can always express this as a `join`:

```
select sso.stat, sso.shno, sso.orderno, o.OrderNoTotal
from (select STAT, SHNO, ORDERNO
      from BLUEWATER
      group by STAT, SHNO, ORDERNO
     ) sso join
     (select OrderNo, count(distinct SHNO) as OrderNoTotal
      from BlueWater
      group by OrderNo
     ) o
     on o.OrderNo = sso.OrderNo;
```

Comment: It complains of an incorrect syntax near '('. Is there something I need to correct ?

Comment: @TobyDerrum . . . I don't notice anything obvious.

Comment: Sorry, it must have been a poor copy paste job. Although now the calculation is wrong. OrderNoTotal does not exclude ORDERNO - SHNO duplicates which is the key requirement.